# Is there a way to dynamically expand & "attach" a JSON object in R?

Tags: r

I am reading a JSON file every day from a server. The size of the file is quite large, usually between 3 and 5 MB. The structure of the "top-level" table of the file is always similar, but there are many "nested" R dataframes within the different columns of the table. I'm looking for a way to dynamically expand the dataframe that is read in from the file based on the column names of each of the sub-items. An example of what the dataframe looks like below:

The High-Level Table

| id | name | htn | atn | start | options | end |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | XX | a01 | z26 | 1/1/22 | 1158 variables | 2/2/22 |
| 2 | YY | b02 | y25 | 1/1/22 | 1165 variables | 2/2/22 |
| 3 | ZZ | c03 | x24 | 1/1/22 | 1158 variables | 2/2/22 |
| 4 | AA | d04 | w23 | 1/1/22 | 1243 variables | 2/2/22 |
| 5 | BB | e05 | v22 | 1/1/22 | 15 variables | 2/2/22 |

If, in RStudio, I click into the first row of the Options table, I get another table:

| id | label | outcome | other |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a1 | test01 | 7 variables | NA |
| a2 | test02 | 7 variables | NA |
| a3 | test04 | 5 variables | NA |
| a4 | test05 | 7 variables | NA |
| a5 | test08 | 5 variables | NA |

Then, if I click into the first row of the Outcomes table, I get a third layer down:

| id | label | ln | odda | oddb | oddf | name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| b01 | XX | ## | string01 | ## | string01 | HTA |
| b02 | XX | ## | string02 | ## | string02 | BCM |

As can be seen, each of the "sub-tables" is of different size and different columns, with some overlapping names. Is there a way to "expand" the highest level tables to concatenate / aggregate the lower level tables in R?

Comment: Have you looked at the `unnest` function from `tidyr`? If you want more help than a pointer like that, you may need to create a small reproducible example---can you build something with a similar structure but small enough to share in your question?

Comment: Thanks for your comment - I was able to use unnest to expand the columns. One question - if there are additional columns to expand, would it be possible to identify them dynamically?

Comment: Look at the column classes, only columns of class `list` can be unnested. `sapply(your_data, is.list)` should work pretty well.

Comment: Very helpful, thanks! Next will need to write a function to take that sapply, along with 'unnest' and run it recursively.

Comment: I wouldn't use recursion, a `while` loop would be clean and avoid problems of copying the data down the recursive stack.